# Howto create indexes using Loopback 3 and mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, frameworks, loopbackjs, loopback3

I have a model definition as such (snipped for sake of readability):

```
{
  "name": "PlannerArchive",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true,
    "strictObjectIDCoercion": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "planner": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": true
    },
    "event": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "user": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "indexes": {                    <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    "event_idx": {
      "keys": {
        "event": 1
      }
    },
    "user_idx": {
      "keys": {
        "user": 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My expectation is that when the server has started up and the collection has been created - that the indexes be created as well.

The reality is that the collection is created, and a PK index on generated "id" is created - but none of my custom indexes are.

I can run code on server boot that looks something like `mongoDS.autoupdate()` that will create them, but was rather hoping not to need to do this.

Is my understanding of loopbacks index handling flawed - or is there something else I can do?

Apologies for still running Loopback 3.x - the migration is in the pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

When adding indexes, you need an auto-update script.

Add it in `/server/boot/autoupdate.js`:

```
'use strict';
var Promise = require('bluebird');

module.exports = function (server) {

    Promise.each(server.models(), function (model) {

        if (model.dataSource) {
            var autoupdate = Promise.promisify(model.dataSource.autoupdate);
            if (autoupdate) {
                return autoupdate.call(model.dataSource, model.modelName);
            }
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: hi.  thanks for your response.  as i mentioned i am already doing something similar. i guess my expectation was that since i am configuring the indexes in the model - that the framework would actually "take care of them" - instead of me having to write code to do it.

Comment: Yes it's not the case, effectively